# Looknig for resources on finding periodic orbit and stability on multidimensional Hamiltonian systems

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, hamiltonian, stability, integrable-systems

I am looking for resources (books, papers, algorithms, codes) that explicitly explain the computation and analysis (using the monodromy matrix) of periodic orbits of multidimensional Hamiltonian systems.